# Choosing which side to rotate

Tags: c++, rotation, 2d

I'm implementing a homing bullet that targets the nearest enemy.

I'm able to calculate the angle between the player's forward vector and the vector from the player to the target by doing a dot product.
If I put the result to acos(), it will give me the angle between the 2 vectors in terms of radian.

Now I want my object to rotate and face toward the enemy as it is flying. But here comes the problem, how do I know which side to rotate to? I know the angle between the 2 vectors, but I dot producted value doesnt tell me whether or not the target is on the left side or right side of the player.

I'm wondering if I'm taking a longer route, and I might not be aware of a easier way to determine how much and to which side I need to rotate to face the target.

Comment: I think this would work for you, I just scanned it though:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022446/direction-of-shortest-rotation-between-two-vectors?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to get the direction, in which your spaceship `vecS` should rotate in order to look at the target `vecT`.

I would suggest to calculate the angle `alpha`, which `vecS` and the x-axis enclose, as well as the angle `beta`, which `vecT` and the x-axis enclose.
If `alpha` is greater than `beta` you would rotate to the right, otherwise to the left.

Here is the pseudocode to calculate the angle and the proper rotation direction:

```
// Pseudocode:
alpha = arctan( vecS.y / vecS.x );
beta = arctan ( vecT.y / vecS.x );

if(alpha > beta)
  // Rotate right by alpha - beta
else
  // Rotate left by alpha - beta
```

Comment: This way won't work, 'cos you can't find exact angle just by it's tangent.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail please?

Comment: For example, Tangent( 135 ) == Tangent( -45 ), but they are opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate dot product for side vector like this:

```
vector Side( Front.Y, -Front.X );
float dotSide = dot( Target, Side );
if( dotSide <= 0 )
{
    // one side
}
else
{
    // another side
}
```